# Terraform supported regex to validate s3 bucket naming rules

Tags: regex, amazon-s3, terraform

I'm implementing Terraform configs for creating a s3 bucket and I would like to validate that the s3 bucket name validates aws s3 naming rules.

Currently I have the following validation block in my variable "bucket_name" block:

```
validation {
    condition     = can(regex("(?!(^xn--|.+-s3alias$))^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]$", var.bucket_name))
    error_message = "s3 bucket name must follow aws s3 naming rules"
  }
```

however a valid s3 bucket name is failing this validation rule with "Error: Invalid value for variable".

With further investigation, it seems that Terraform regex uses Golang regex which seems to not support negative lookahead. Is there a way to write a regex that achieves the same goal of validating the s3 bucket naming rules, but that works with Terraform and won't cause valid s3 bucket names to fail that validation rule?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use just a single regex? An expression like this could suit, and be clearer:

```
condition = (
    can(regex("^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]$", var.bucket_name)) && 
    !strcontains(var.bucket_name, "..") && 
    !startswith(var.bucket_name, "xn--") && 
    !startswith(var.bucket_name, "sthree-") && 
    !endswith(var.bucket_name, "-s3alias") && 
    !endswith(var.bucket_name, "--ol-s3")
)
```

This should check for most of the requirements [listed by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html) as of today. Naturally, it doesn't check whether the bucket name is already taken. It also disallows the use of periods in the name, as suggested on that page and as you have already done.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @lxop answer to break down the condition, complex `regex` are hard to read, and only one message makes it even harder for the end user to troubleshoot why is the bucket name they chosen fails validation. I took it a step further and broke it down to individual conditions each one with own specific message.

I was surprised that no one has done something like that, seems like an easy way to validate bucket names, and a nice example of what can be done with terraform validation.

Here is my attempt to cover what is defined in `General purpose buckets naming rules`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html

```hcl
variable "bucket_name" {
  type = string

  validation {
    condition     = length(var.bucket_name) >= 3 && length(var.bucket_name) <= 63
    error_message = "Bucket names must be between 3 (min) and 63 (max) characters long"
  }

  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("^[a-z0-9.-]{1,64}$", var.bucket_name))
    error_message = "Bucket names can consist only of lowercase letters, numbers, dots (.), and hyphens (-)."
  }

  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("^[a-z0-9].*[a-z0-9]$", var.bucket_name))
    error_message = "Bucket names must begin and end with a letter or number"
  }

  validation {
    condition     = !strcontains(var.bucket_name, "..")
    error_message = "Bucket names must not contain two adjacent periods."
  }

  validation {
    condition     = !can(regex("^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}$", var.bucket_name))
    error_message = "Bucket names must not be formatted as an IP address (for example, 192.168.5.4)"
  }

  validation {
    condition     = !startswith(var.bucket_name, "xn--")
    error_message = "Bucket names must not start with the prefix xn--"
  }

  validation {
    condition     = !startswith(var.bucket_name, "sthree-")
    error_message = "Bucket names must not start with the prefix sthree-"
  }

  validation {
    condition     = !endswith(var.bucket_name, "-s3alias")
    error_message = "Bucket names must not end with the suffix -s3alias."
  }

  validation {
    condition     = !endswith(var.bucket_name, "--ol-s3")
    error_message = "Bucket names must not end with the suffix --ol-s3"
  }
}
```

And to that you can add any validations that your organization might have.